# Need suggestion on a customizable dualList react component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, bootstrap-duallistbox

I am working on a webApp which I started off with create-react-app. It implements redux, and has dynamic data being loaded with axios calls.
I need suggestions for a **customisable** dualList box component, which supports custom item components and event handlers.

I've already tried react-dual-listbox, but it does not support custom selected Item components.

Comment: Could you add an example (image or simple code) of your dual list box and how you'd like to customize it?

Answer (score 0):

It does not allow custom selected components for selected items because it can't! The list looks like this in html / react jsx

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="banana">Banana</option>
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="orange">Orange</option>
  <option value="pinapple">Pinapple</option>
</select>
```

There are various options, but you could start with creating your own list implementation with divs and buttons and track which element the user has clicked on and apply different styles to indicate it's active.

```
const { activeElement } = this.state;

<List>
  <ListItem isActive={activeElement === 'banana'} icon="banana">Banana</ListItem>
  <ListItem isActive={activeElement === 'apple'} icon="apple">Apple</ListItem>
  <ListItem isActive={activeElement === 'orange'} icon="orange">Orange</ListItem>
  <ListItem isActive={activeElement === 'pineapple'} icon={<SomeSvgIconThatLooksLikePineapple />}>Pineapple</ListItem>
</List>
```

Also clickHandlers are not added to this example. It takes some effort but it's not hard to achieve. In your case, I guess you get data from redux as a list, so you might map over your results and apply a different ListItem component that matches your type.